# SharedPreference во fragment'e выдает ошибку

Tags: java, android

во фрагменете:

```
public class Profile extends Fragment  {

SharedPreferences sPref;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);

    sPref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PROFILE", 0);

    return view;
}

public void save() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putString("NAME", nameE.getText().toString());
    ed.putString("WEIGHT", weightE.getText().toString());
    ed.commit();

}

public void load() {
    nameT.setText(sPref.getString("NAME", ""));
    weightT.setText(sPref.getString("WEIGHT", ""));
    }
}
```

в Активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener  {

Fragment profile;
Profile pro = new Profile();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myscroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myscroll);
    buttonsEat = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonsEat);
    buttonsEat.setVisibility(GONE);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mode = Mode.NORMAL;

    NavDrawerInit();

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        setFragment(0, Upraznenia.class);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_main, menu);
    editButton = menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit);
    saveButton = menu.findItem(R.id.action_save);

    startMode(mode);

    return true;
}


private void startMode(Mode modeToStart) {
    if (modeToStart == Mode.NORMAL) {
        editButton.setVisible(false);
        saveButton.setVisible(false);
        mode = modeToStart;
    }
    if (modeToStart == Mode.EDIT) {
        editButton.setVisible(true);
        saveButton.setVisible(false);
        mode = modeToStart;
    }
    if (modeToStart == Mode.SAVE) {
        editButton.setVisible(false);
        saveButton.setVisible(true);
        mode = modeToStart;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.equals(editButton)) {
        startMode(Mode.SAVE);
        profile = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
        ((LinearLayout) profile.getView().findViewById(R.id.editLayout)).setVisibility(GONE);
        ((LinearLayout) profile.getView().findViewById(R.id.saveLayout)).setVisibility(VISIBLE);

    }
    if (item.equals(saveButton)) {
        startMode(Mode.EDIT);
        pro.save();
        pro.load();
        ((LinearLayout) profile.getView().findViewById(R.id.editLayout)).setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        ((LinearLayout) profile.getView().findViewById(R.id.saveLayout)).setVisibility(GONE);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void NavDrawerInit(){
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mLvDrawerMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_drawer_menu);
    List<DrawerMenuItem> menuItems = generateDrawerMenuItems();
    DrawerMenuItemAdapter mDrawerMenuAdapter = new DrawerMenuItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), menuItems);
    mLvDrawerMenu.setAdapter(mDrawerMenuAdapter);
    mLvDrawerMenu.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();

        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}


}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mLvDrawerMenu)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLvDrawerMenu);
    } else {
        if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis())
            super.onBackPressed();

        else

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Нажмите еще раз, чтобы выйти",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

public void setFragment(int position, Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass) {
    try {
        Fragment fragment = fragmentClass.newInstance();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, fragmentClass.getSimpleName());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        mLvDrawerMenu.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLvDrawerMenu);
        mLvDrawerMenu.invalidateViews();
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("setFragment", ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private List<DrawerMenuItem> generateDrawerMenuItems() {
    String[] itemsText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
    TypedArray itemsIcon = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
    List<DrawerMenuItem> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < itemsText.length; i++) {
        DrawerMenuItem item = new DrawerMenuItem();
        item.setText(itemsText[i]);
        item.setIcon(itemsIcon.getResourceId(i, -1));
        result.add(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

при вызове `pro.save();` выскакивает ошибка `NullPointer`, уже все перепробовал, но так и не найду где допустил оплошность.

Comment: В коде не хватает двух переменных, когда сюда копировал, чистил код и забыл их прикрепить, но они есть, так что проблема не в них

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фрагмент получает доступ к активити только в/после метода `onAttach()`

Т.е. вам надо перенести код, завязанный на Активити в него:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
super.onAttach(activity);
sPref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PROFILE", 0);
}
```

**Обновление:**

В вашей активити вам надо profile переменную скастовать к классу фрагмена и на ней вызывать методы. Переменная pro не добавлена в активити и оттого и NPE

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробуем)

Comment: Только учтите, что фрагмент надо ещё в активити добавить. По приведённому вами коду не понятно, сделали вы это или нет. Если нет, то и методы жизненного цикла фрагмента вызваны не будут и вы продолжите получать ошибку.

Comment: profile = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
Если вы про это, то объявлял.

Comment: Ага, тогда всё должно сработать.

Comment: сделал, но опять ошибка

Comment: NPE? А в активити этот код работает?

Comment: NPE опять,та должен работать в активити

Comment: А что именно null - `sPref`  или `profile`?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at Имяпакета.Profile.save(Profile.java:69)
в 69 строке:
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();

Comment: А в активити вы в каком месте вызываете save? Если по клику или в onResume - то должно работать. В onCreate не будет.

Comment: в onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: Приведите код в вопросе отвечающий за добавление фрагмента и onOptionsItemSelected.

Comment: Поправил, там код конечно не до конца почищен, но основные моменты есть

Comment: См. Обновление ответа. Ваш фрагмент таки не добвлен в активити

Comment: А можете помочь скастовать? Ни разу не делал)

Comment: Ст елефона не могу норм. Нарисать.  Просто поместите перед выражением получения фрагмента имя его класса в скобках.

Comment: Ура заработало)